# Weblogic 12c - the Node Manager associated with machine P360DeploymentMachine is not reachable

Tags: weblogic12c

I am trying to start a server on the weblogic getting this error:
the Node Manager associated with machine P360DeploymentMachine is not reachable.

This is my machine and node manager on WebLogic:

[image]

Error I am getting:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Make sure your NodeManager uses the same setting as you set in the AdminServer.  I set my NodeManager to use plain socket in the AdminServer but the actual NodeManager started in secured socket by default.  Check you NodeManager log to confirm.  For example, this is in my log

```
<Nov 3, 2016 9:22:45 PM EDT> <INFO> <Secure socket listener started on port 5556, host /192.168.2.3>
```

and I got the unreachable error. After I changed the parameter `SecureListener=false` in `nodemanager.properties`, I could start the server just fine.

Comment: This was the case for me too. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing this issues. After trying several methods, I realised that I was not running Node Manager service.

For starting Node Manager service,  you need to go to

1. C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\bin\startNodeManager.cmd  (Specific to my PC)
2. Run with admin privileges.

It solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
Below is the solution to the problem:
1. Actually we need to make sure we add the path of domain folder like below in "nodemanager.domains" file which is present in your weblogic folder in my case its at below path "C:\weblogic\wlserver\common\nodemanager"
values in "nodemanager.domains"
base_domain=C\:\\weblogic\\user_projects\\domains\\base_domain
AbcDomain=D\:\\Projects\\Abc\\trunk\\10X\\deploy\\AbcDomain
2. Make sure "SecureListener=false" in file "nodemanager.properties" at location "C:\weblogic\wlserver\common\nodemanager" (This is mymachine to you need to find relative path in your machine.
3. Make sure the port numbers for each of the manager servers are different and correct example 80001, 8002 and so on....dont use 7001 for manager server as this is already used by admin server.
if we do this my issue was resoled and i am sure the orginal posted issue also should be resolved.
```

Answer (score 1):

Connect to the weblogic server using connect(). Provide the details. make sure you connect to the admin server using the ts protocol i.e t3://a.b.c.d:port

enroll the node manager.

stop the node manager and start it again. That worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have faced similar issues i have done lot of research finally tested the troubleshooting with a very simple trick just manually start the ManagedWeblogic server

just run the below command in cmd as admin

```
cd C:\Oracle\user_projects\domains\base_domain\bin 
startManagedWebLogic.cmd ODI_server1 http://localhost:7001
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I shutdown one of my servers (on the `Summary of Servers -> Control` tab), and how to start it again was in no way obvious.

In my particular case, it was actually very simple: start it again using the Windows Services snap-in (`Start -> Run -> services.msc`). A service exists there for each of the servers that I have configured in WebLogic. (Note that after starting the service, it could take a couple of minutes for the status in the WebLogic console to reflect the `RUNNING` state.)

No need to configure the Node Manager in this case!

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to give you a definitive answer without seeing some additional config files. These are the places i would check first

- Full restart of the nodemanager service (ensure it comes up cleanly)
- Check the port the nodemanager is running on

Do other managed servers startup or is this the first one you have built?

Happy to help more if you can provide some additional information

AB

Answer (score 0):

```
I am also facing same error with same settings as seen the snap shot shared by "Hbargujar", Please find below details on my machine and if you can help me, let me know if you need any specific details of configuration as well.
Version of weblogic: 10.3.6.0
Configured below elements:
Managed Servers:
1. ManagedServer-0
2. ManagedServer-1

Cluster: 
    cluster1

Machine:
    MachineForCluster-0

Config File has below server settings to map machine to AdminServer:
  <server>
    <name>AdminServer</name>
    <machine>MachineForCluster-0</machine>
    <listen-address>localhost</listen-address>
  </server>

Error Message: For server ManagedServer-0, the Node Manager associated with machine MachineForCluster-0 is not reachable.
Message icon - Warning All of the servers selected are currently in a state which is incompatible with this operation or are not associated with a running Node Manager or you are not authorized to perform the action requested. No action will be performed.

I tried to start Node manager by using below command:
    startNodeManager(verbose='true',NodeManagerHome='C:\\weblogic\\wlserver\\common\    \nodemanager',ListenPort='5556',ListenAddress='localhost')
but 
its didn't start with port "5556" but if i give some other port number it starts however when i start managed server from admin console i get the same error messages as above.

Let me know i am missing anything here...
```

Answer (score 0):

How I resolved:

Listen Address: Remove localhost and put the FQDN - hostname+domain_name

Go to >> nodemanager/nodemanager.properties (in Weblogic Server)
Edit the ListenAddress= to hostanme+domain_name.

Restart the managed services.